# Tensorflow allocates 4 times more memory in cpu than binary model size

Tags: c++, tensorflow, c-api

We are using tensorflow C API version 1.13.1
from here https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c

Our neural network model ***frozen_graph.pb*** size is 230mb  with ***MobileNet*** architecture.
When we loading it, tensorflow allocates about 1.1 gb on first session run,  and than  memory allocation reduces to ~900mb and remains in this value.

We  tried  graph transform tool from here
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/README.md  to optimize graph.
But only quantization seems to be effective to reduce also model size, also memory usage.But occasionally we can't use it as quantization reduces model accuracy by 15%.

As we currently think the only way to reduce  model size   and do not drastically affect accuracy is.

1)Move to another back end like MXNET etc...

2)Use knowledge distillation technique to retrain small models.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.02531.pdf

We are expecting that memory allocation for single model do not exceeds 150% of binary size.
Any solution acceptable.
Thank you.

Comment: *"We are expecting that memory allocation for single model do not exceeds 150% of binary size"*  - Why?

Comment: Because we have to support multiple instance of same model in server so we have to diminish memory as much as  possible

Comment: I am not asking why you want to reduce the model memory consumption, but why you assume that the model in memory should be at most 150% the size of the model in its binary form?

Comment: Because i wrote my small back end in c++ and there memory usage not exceeds 140% of binary model size.

Comment: Also mxnet is the same  not more then 170%  memory allocated for models